# Play Javascript Router - exporting and using the javascript router outside of the play framework

Tags: javascript, playframework-2.0, browserify, playframework-2.3

I'm currently developing a phonegap app intended to connect to my Play webservice. I would love to be able to use the play javascript router to connect to my webservice but I've got a couple of problems that are prohibiting me.

1) I can't embed the full domain name in the routes, as it appears to be intended only for use when served by the play server, and routes are relative to the server. In phonegap, I need the full domain name. Is there a way to specify the base URL for the call?

2) I'm doing extensive modularization using browserify, which requires export statements on all local files so that the vars/functions can be imported into my javascript code using require('../lib/javascriptRouter.js'). After browserifying the file, it goes through a minification step, which will mangle names if the dependencies aren't managed by browserify. The current javascript router does not generate these exports. Is there a way to generate these?

3) This one is more of an annoyance than anything. I would like the generated javascript router to be made available at some configurable target build path, instead of trying to track it down manually. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

1) + 3): The JavaScript router is meant to be exposed at a given route, e.g. `http://your.app.com/jsroutes` (see [here](https://github.com/mariussoutier/play-angular-require-seed/blob/master/app%2Fcontrollers%2FApplication.scala#L40-L44) and [here](https://github.com/mariussoutier/play-angular-require-seed/blob/master/conf%2Froutes#L8-L9)). Your PhoneGap app would have to know the server whose jsRoutes it is using.

2) You cannot influence how the jsRoutes script looks, but can't Browserify handle these situations? With RequireJS, you can simply wrap it, [see here](https://github.com/mariussoutier/play-angular-require-seed/blob/master/app%2Fassets%2Fjavascripts%2Fmain.js#L10).